# Count and Time window in Esper EPL

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I have the following use case, which I'm trying to write in EPL, without success. I'm generating analytics events of different types, generated in different intervals (1min, 5min, 10min, ...). In special kind of analytics, I need to collect 4 specific 
 Analytics events (from which I will count another analytic event) of different types, returned every interval (1min, 5min, 10min, ...). The condition there is, that on every whole interval, e.g., every whole minute 00:01:00, 00:02:00 I want to have returned either 4 events or nothing if the events don't arrive in some slack period after (e.g., 2s).

case 1: events A,B,C,D arrive at times 00:01:00.500, 00:01:00.600, 00:01:00.700, 00:01:00.800 - right after fourth event arrives to esper, the aggregated event with all 4 events is returned

case 2: slack period is 2seconds, events A,B,C,D arrives at 00:01:00.500, 00:01:00.600, 00:01:00.700, 00:01:02.200 - nothing is arrived, as the last event is out of the slack period

Answer (score 1):

You could create a trigger event every minute like this:

```
insert into TriggerEvent select * from pattern[timer:schedule(date:'1970-01-01T00:00:00.0Z', period: 1 minute, repetitions: -1)]
```

The trigger that arrives every minute can kick off a pattern or context. A pattern would seem to be good enough. Here is something like that:

```
select * from pattern [every TriggerEvent -> (a=A -> b=B -> c=C -> d=D) where timer:within(2 seconds)]
```